velocity command topic with diff drive controller
I'm working with a robot simulation and now U have encountered a small issue. Before when I used to launch my other robot from other project I could see cmd_vel topic but now on this one, I see that it changes to diffdrivecontroller/cmd_vel. I tried everything I could to change it but no luck (also, i don't want to remap the topic, i just want to know why it happens) any help would be appreciated. I will link my URDF snippet, controller file and the lunch file below.
thanks.
launch file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="-2.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="-0.5"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <!-- <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/> -->
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find bot)/urdf/mybot.urdf" />
  
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find bot)/config/control.yaml" />


  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" 
        args="diff_drive_controller joint_state_controller" />

  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  
        args="-urdf -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description -model my_robot" />
</launch>

URDF Snippet:
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="diff_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
    <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
    <leftJoint>front_left_wheel_joint, rear_left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
    <rightJoint>front_right_wheel_joint, rear_right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
    <wheelSeparation>0.5</wheelSeparation>
    <wheelDiameter>0.2</wheelDiameter>
    <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
    <publishTf>false</publishTf>
    <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
    <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
    <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
    <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
    <wheelAcceleration>2.8</wheelAcceleration>
    <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
    <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
    <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
    <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
  </plugin>

control.yaml:
joint_state_controller:
  type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
  publish_rate: 50

diff_drive_controller:
  type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel: ['front_left_wheel_joint', 'rear_left_wheel_joint']
  right_wheel: ['front_right_wheel_joint', 'rear_right_wheel_joint']
  publish_rate: 50
  pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03]
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
  wheel_separation : 0.445208
  wheel_radius : 0.0625
  base_frame_id: base_link
  odom_frame_id: odom
  enable_odom_tf: true
  estimate_velocity_from_position: false
  wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0 
  wheel_radius_multiplier    : 1.0 
  linear:
    x:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 2.0   
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 3.0   
  angular:
    z:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 3.0   
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 6.0   

/gazebo_ros_control:
    pid_gains:
      front_left_wheel_joint: {p: 20.0, i: 0.01, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0}
      front_right_wheel_joint: {p: 20.0, i: 0.01, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0}
      rear_left_wheel_joint: {p: 20.0, i: 0.01, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0}
      rear_right_wheel_joint: {p: 20.0, i: 0.01, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0}



Check Namespaces in Launch Files

Inspect your launch file for  tags or namespace attributes.
<group ns="diffdrivecontroller">
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="diff_drive_controller joint_state_controller" />
</group>

Remove the namespace or move controller_spawner outside the  tag to avoid topic prefixing.

Update control.yaml

Explicitly set the cmd_vel topic in your control.yaml (wouldn't recommend in actual project, is a band-aid fix):
diff_drive_controller:
  type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel: ['front_left_wheel_joint', 'rear_left_wheel_joint']
  right_wheel: ['front_right_wheel_joint', 'rear_right_wheel_joint']
  cmd_vel_topic: '/cmd_vel'  # Force the topic to /cmd_vel

This ensures consistency regardless of namespaces.

Verify Node and Controller Names

Ensure the controller_spawner node name and arguments match your expectations.
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="diff_drive_controller joint_state_controller" />

Check for unintended prefixing in the name (diffdrivecontroller).

Debug with ROS Tools

Use these commands:
List topics: rostopic list (Check if cmd_vel is prefixed).
Inspect node: rosnode info /controller_spawner (View subscribed/published topics).

Choose a Consistent Approach
Option 1: Gazebo ROS Diff Drive Plugin
URDF:
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_diff_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
  <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
  <leftJoint>left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
  <rightJoint>right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
</plugin>

Launch File: Remove controller_spawner.
Option 2: ROS Control Diff Drive Controller
URDF:
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so"/>

Add transmissions for wheel joints.
Control YAML:
diff_drive_controller:
  type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  cmd_vel_topic: '/cmd_vel'

Launch File: Include controller_spawner.

This appears to be a ros1 question, not ros2, so your ros2_control "ros__parameters" answer is going to be confusing to them.

Im extremely sorry for the mixup, my actual control file isnot like this actually.  i have edited the file to incorporate the og file i use

i tied that but then it would just be like this, '''rostopic list
/clock
/cmd_vel/cmd_vel
/cmd_vel/odom
/cmd_vel/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel/parameter_updates'''

There are multiple ways to simulate a diff-drive robot, but you need to be consistent and implement just one of them. Right now what you've shown us is a mixture of old-school libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so, and the newer-style ros_control. These two approaches are not compatible with each other.
If you want to go old-school, look at the turtle* package files (there are many.) If you want to use the ros_control approach, look at the rosbot or jackal package files. Unfortunately none of these examples are very concise, so the important pieces are spread across multiple directories.
Update: the ros1 noetic Turtlebot3 ros packages:
turtle_actionlib
turtlebot3
turtlebot3_bringup
turtlebot3_description
turtlebot3_example
turtlebot3_fake
turtlebot3_gazebo
turtlebot3_msgs
turtlebot3_navigation
turtlebot3_simulations
turtlebot3_slam
turtlebot3_teleop
turtlesim
turtle_tf
turtle_tf2


yes to check turtlebot3 was my initial thought and when i checked for control files, i found there was control file only in the turtlebot3_slam package but those are just carto or gmapping yaml files. i could not find anythng on the diff drive
